# Assigning a value of a String to a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I doing some coding related to my project. I need to assign simply a string value to a String array reading from a file.

But I can't understand why the value keeps always null. The values of string doesn't assign to the array. Can someone explains me the mistake I have done.

Here I have posted my code.

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Tuning Jaccard Coefficient algorithm for Training set
        ReadFile_2 rf = new ReadFile_2();         
        rf.readFile("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Msc-2016/InformationRetrieval/project material/train.txt","Training");
    }
}
```

**ReadFile_2.java**

```
class ReadFile_2 {

    List<String> copying_strings1 = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] Apparted_Strings = new String[3];
    String[] copying_strings = new String[50];
    int arryListSize = copying_strings.length;
    static int value_of_shingle;
    static int best_Shingle;
    String[] fileType;
    int fileType_size;

    public void readFile(String fileName, String file_type) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        //Name of the file
        try {
            if (file_type.equals("Training")) {
                best_Shingle = 2;
            } else if (file_type.equals("Testing")) {
                best_Shingle = value_of_shingle;
            }

            FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
            String line;
            int r = 0;

            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                copying_strings[r] = line;
                r++;
                System.out.println("lll " + copying_strings[r]);
                System.out.println("lll " +line);
                //Apparted_Strings = sp.apart_Strings_3(line);
                //CallingAlgo_4 c_a = new CallingAlgo_4(Apparted_Strings[0], Apparted_Strings[1], Apparted_Strings[2], best_Shingle, "Jaccard");
            }

            //Close the buffer reader
            bufferReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please let me know why the value of

```
System.out.println("lll " + copying_strings[r]);
```

prints always as null.

Comment: `r++;`. You increment `r` between the reading and printing, as a result you print what´s in the next line, but you didn´t assign it yet so you allways have a `null`. remove the `r++` and change the print to `copying_strings[r++]` and you should print the currentline while also incrementing `r` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your `while-loop`. The correct sequence is to read a line first, pass it to String, print it and finally increment the looped variable.

```
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {     // read a line   
    copying_strings[r] = line;                         // pass to String
    System.out.println("lll " + copying_strings[r]);   // print for the 1st time
    System.out.println("lll " + line);                 // print for the 2nd time
    r++;                                               // increment the looped variable
}
```

If you print the variable `copying_strings` after incrementing `r++`, you get obviously `null` because nothing has been passed in it.

Answer (score 0):

- You increment the while loop variable (r) before printing the string value.
- So it prints the next array value that is `null`.

So please increment the variable (r) after printing the string value as mentioned below,

```
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    copying_strings[r] = line;                        
    System.out.println("lll " + copying_strings[r++]);
    System.out.println("lll " +line);                                              
}
```